# Adding JDBC query information to opentracing/Jaeger spans

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, opentracing, jaeger

We're using Opentracing/Jaeger in Istio for tracing multiple Spring Boot/Spring Cloud based microservices.

I'm currently wondering if there's an option to enrich the tracing spans by providing information about executed query (i.e. SQL statement)? Tracing JDBC connection info is working fine using [opentracing-contrib/java-spring-cloud](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-cloud/) but additional information is missing.

I know that e.g. [glowroot](https://glowroot.org/) is capable of tracing the statements itself but haven't found anything related to Opentracing or Jaeger.

Would be great if anybody could show some directions for research!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. ConnectionInfo was getting traced but not the SQL statements.
In my case, I had to enable traceWithActiveSpanOnly=true.

For e.g, : jdbc:tracing:h2:mem:test?traceWithActiveSpanOnly=true

After that the statements started getting traced.

[Check the documentation of opentracing java-jdbc module here](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-jdbc)